# Part of reflection/transmission of an impinging beam under 90°

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

I would like to know if there is something like a thumb of rule for a light beam impinging a surface under $90°$. In regards to [Snelius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) there will be no refraction. But what about the amount of reflected and transmitted light?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection depends on TE or TM polarization and internal or external,
 you can see the behavior of each below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Did you create it? If so, can you please guide me to some more detailed information? :)

Comment: You can find information here: Fundamentals of Photonics,2nd edition, Saleh, chapter 6. If you have question inform me.